# Horizontal swipe gesture on UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml, swipe-gesture

is there any way to get swipe gesture same as windows phone 8 with wptoolkit.
Because wptoolkit nuget package is not available for uwp, so i am unable to get similar swipe gesture on UWP
In windows Phone 8 with the help of WPtoolkit nugetget package
i placed this

```
<toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
         <toolkit:GestureListener Flick="OnSwipe"/>
</toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
```

over text block, so i can swipe left to right or right to left over `textbox1`.
and swipe gesture help me to implement this

```
private static int i;
private void OnSwipe(object sender, FlickGestureEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.HorizontalVelocity < 0)
        {
              i++;
              txtBox1.Text = i.ToString();             
        }

        if (e.HorizontalVelocity > 0)
        {
             i--;
             txtBox1.Text = i.ToString();
        }
    }
```

i tried Manupulation method with scrollViewer on uwp but it continuously increase the value untill it scroll viewer stopped

and this is codes

```
    private static int i;
    private Point initialpoint;
    private void scrollview_ManipulationStarted(object sender, ManipulationStartedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        initialpoint = e.Position;
    }

    private void scrollview_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.IsInertial)
        {
            Point currentpoint = e.Position;
            if (currentpoint.X - initialpoint.X >= 2)
            {
                i++;
                txtBox1.Text = i.ToString();
            }

            if (currentpoint.Y - initialpoint.Y >= 2)
            {
                i--;
                txtBox1.Text = i.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

Any other way to implement same functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you don't need to handle `ManipulationStarted` in this case and you don't need the `initialPoint` property. Assuming you have already defined your `ScrollViewer`'s `ManipulationMode` to the following

```
ManipulationMode="TranslateX,TranslateInertia,System"
```

Then you simply use `e.Cumulative.Translation.X` to tell how long you have swiped in total

```
private void scrollview_ManipulationCompleted(object sender, ManipulationCompletedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.IsInertial)
    {
        var swipedDistance = e.Cumulative.Translation.X;

        if (Math.Abs(swipedDistance) <= 2) return;

        if (swipedDistance > 0)
        {
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            i--;
        }

        txtBox1.Text = i.ToString();
    }
}
```

---

### Update

Now that I understand your question better, I think you should handle gesture manipulation on the `TextBox` itself. If you want instant feedback, simply subscribe to the `ManipulationDelta` event and create a flag to only run the swipe logic once per touch.

```
private bool _isSwiped;
private void txtBox1_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.IsInertial && !_isSwiped)
    {
        var swipedDistance = e.Cumulative.Translation.X;

        if (Math.Abs(swipedDistance) <= 2) return;

        if (swipedDistance > 0)
        {
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            i--;
        }

        txtBox1.Text = i.ToString();

        _isSwiped = true;
    }
}

private void txtBox1_ManipulationCompleted(object sender, ManipulationCompletedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _isSwiped = false;
}
```

Make sure you move all the handlers and set the `ManipulationMode` onto the `TextBox`.

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtBox1"
         ManipulationMode="TranslateX,TranslateInertia,System" 
         ManipulationDelta="txtBox1_ManipulationDelta" 
         ManipulationCompleted="txtBox1_ManipulationCompleted" />
```

Comment: but still it continuously increase until scroll viewer is stopped, 
means it increase the value twice . any other better suggestion in place of scrollviewer

Comment: On Text Block it work little late(after swiping need to wait 1 or 1.5 sec) it is not working instantly

Comment: okay :), oh i just try scroll viewer and text block both work similar it is not work twice , it is work only in 0.5 or1 sec. delay, because of this i incidentally swipe multiple times, but why it work on delay

Comment: Nice :) now its working perfectly without delay instantly. Thanks' YoU for giving your precious time to my question

Comment: Glad it helped!