# Use Swipe Gesture in UWP

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp, swipe, gesture

I've seen that since the latest update (Windows Fall Creators Update) there exists a collection of Swipe Classes, but in the current stable release of VS ( 15.4.1 ) there isn't a way to make it work. I'm currently running the latest W10 update (1709) with Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise ( 15.4.1 ) and there's no way to make it work. I've tried to make the following example work but with no luck: https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Windows/Windows-Developer-Day-Fall-Creators-Update/WinDev015#comments

Comment: If you dont want to work on that specific example which link you provided, than i can help you to implement swipe gesture in uwp, i already implemented in my one of uwp app through manipulation method,but it is for only swipe and if you want swipe delete action you can use uwp community toolkit also, which one you want? Only swipe or swipe for delete

Comment: Only swipe @ShubhamSahu

Comment: i posted an answer , with min requirement 10.0.10240 with vs 2015 , so you don't need to update anything

Comment: @ShubhamSahu Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am applying swipe on a TextBlock you can apply on your control.

**XAML**

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <TextBlock Name="SwipeableTextBlock" 
               HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
               VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
               TextAlignment="Center" Text="No Swipe"
               FontSize="65" FontWeight="Light"
               ManipulationMode="TranslateX,TranslateInertia,System" 
               ManipulationDelta="SwipeableTextBlock_ManipulationDelta"
               ManipulationCompleted="SwipeableTextBlock_ManipulationCompleted"/>
</Grid>
```

**C#**

```
private bool _isSwiped;

private void SwipeableTextBlock_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.IsInertial && !_isSwiped)
    {
        var swipedDistance = e.Cumulative.Translation.X;

        if (Math.Abs(swipedDistance) <= 2) return;

        if (swipedDistance > 0)
        {
            SwipeableTextBlock.Text = "Right Swiped";
        }
        else
        {
            SwipeableTextBlock.Text = "Left Swiped";
        }
        _isSwiped = true;
    }            
}

    private void SwipeableTextBlock_ManipulationCompleted(object sender, ManipulationCompletedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _isSwiped = false;
    }
```

**Output** 
(Works On PC and Mobile Both)
also credits to [@JustinXL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45550684/horizontal-swipe-gesture-on-uwp) answer  and this is sample [repository](https://github.com/shubdragon/SwipeGestureRepoUWP)

[image: Output]