# UWP Desktop mouse won't trigger the gesture

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, xamarin.uwp

Do we have a way to activate mouse gesture on UWP Desktop for a computer that does not have touch capability? On IOS (in the simulator) we can use the mouse to do PullToRefresh or CellSwipe on Listview.

I use Xamarin.forms

Comment: Check my answer on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46962632/use-swipe-gesture-in-uwp/46986410#46986410 you can put swipe gesture on any element

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the `ListView` control in Xamarin.Forms doesn't Support *PullToRefresh* or *CellSwipe* on UWP. So you have to implement these functionalities by yourself and you can use the code provided by Shubham Sahu in the comments or you take a look at third pary libraries like Syncfusion. They provide also a `ListView` Control which is already able to handle *PullToRefresh* or *CellSwipe* on UWP.

Comment: I currently use Telerik Listview for my projet. But like the Telerik support tell me this is platform specific. No gesture on UWP, the limitation is not in the xamarin or Telerik UI.
https://www.telerik.com/forums/pull-to-refresh-in-viewmodel#v0P0_p_iLk2hTGigV7xOOg

Comment: The controls of Syncfusion are supporting both scenarios also on UWP on desktop and mobile. Otherwise you need to implement it for yourself as Shubham Sahu mentioned.